# SageMaker using PCA batch transform output to K-Means data type error

Tags: python, k-means, pca, amazon-sagemaker

I have the output file from PCA batch transform job "processed_features.csv.out" looks like in JSON format `{"projection":[0.248282819986343  -0.494019   -0.23275601863861]}` in S3. I can also retrieve this file in this location `'s3://path1/path2/path3/model_artifacts/pca/transform/'`, and the location can also be retrieved by `pca_transformer.output_path` However, when I try to use this file to train a K-Means model using the code below the job failed.

```
job_name = "clustering-kmeans-" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", localtime())

image = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve(
    framework="kmeans", region=aws_region, version="lastest"
)

kmeans_main = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    image,
    role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    volume_size=50,
    output_path= model_output_path + 'kmeans/train/'+ job_name,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
)

kmeans_main.set_hyperparameters(
    k = 8,
    feature_dim = 3,
)

kmeans_main.fit({'train': pca_transformer.output_path})
```

The job failed and gave me this error message:

```
ClientError: Unable to read data channel 'train'. Requested content-type is 'application/x-recordio-protobuf'. Please verify the data matches the requested content-type. (caused by MXNetError) Caused by: [20:15:32] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs-2.0.4931.0/AL2_x86_64/generic-flavor/src/src/aialgs/io/iterator_base.cpp:100: (Input Error) The header of the MXNet RecordIO record at position 0 in the dataset does not start with a valid magic number. Stack trace returned 10 entries: [bt] (0) /opt/amazon/lib/libaialgs.so(+0x9d1b) [0x7fb0d19acd1b] [bt] (1) /opt/amazon/lib/libaialgs.so(+0xa549) [0x7fb0d19ad549] [bt] (2) /opt/amazon/lib/libaialgs.so(aialgs::iterator_base::Next()+0x448) [0x7fb0d19ba128] [bt] (3) /opt/amazon/lib/libmxnet.so(MXDataIterNext+0x21) [0x7fb0b932c121] [bt] (4) /opt/amazon/lib/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7fb0d19d0078] [bt] (5) /opt/amazon/lib/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x186) [0x7fb0d19cf206] [bt] (6) /opt/amazon/python3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
```

[image]
I found this method in this example: https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_batch_transform/introduction_to_batch_transform/batch_transform_pca_dbscan_movie_clusters.html#Batch-prediction-PCA.

I also read that PCA results are returned in either application/json or application/x-recordioprotobuf format with a vector of "projections." And this format should be accepted by K-Means. I'm not sure what I did wrong here.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

K-means built-in algorithm requires either `recordIO-wrapped-protobuf` and `CSV` formats for training (See [Input/Output Interface for the K-Means Algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/k-means.html#km-inputoutput)).